# Impossible to route: org.mule.transport.amqp.AmqpMessage

Tags: rabbitmq, mule, amqp, connector, mule-component

I'm having a random problem with amqp components in Mule.

This is the scenario:

**I set a global AMQP connector to be used for both Mule Flows**

```
<amqp:connector 
    name="amqpLocalhostConnector"
    host="${amqp.host}"
    port="${amqp.port}"
    fallbackAddresses="${amqp.fallbackAddresses}"
    virtualHost="${amqp.virtualHost}"
    username="${amqp.username}"
    password="${amqp.password}"
    ackMode="MANUAL"
    prefetchCount="1" />
```

**This flows sends a notification to RabbitMQ**

```
<flow 
    name="notifyRabbitMQ" 
    doc:name="notifyRabbitMQ">

    <!-- Set the payload with an ID from an element in a database -->
    <set-payload 
        doc:name="Set Payload" 
        value="123abc"/>

    <!-- Send the ID into an amqp message to RabbitMQ -->
    <amqp:outbound-endpoint 
        exchangeName="exchange"
        routingKey="file.id"
        connector-ref="amqpLocalhostConnector">
    </amqp:outbound-endpoint>

</flow>
```

**This flow gets the notification from the RabbitMQ queue and then process it.**

```
<flow 
    name="processNotification" 
    doc:name="processNotification"
    processingStrategy="synchronous">

    <amqp:inbound-endpoint 
        queueName="files"
        connector-ref="amqpLocalhostConnector" />

    <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Message to String (ID)"/>

    <set-payload 
        value="#[app.registry.customFileService.findFile(payload)]" 
        doc:name="Get File" />

    <logger message="SUCCESS!" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

    <amqp:acknowledge-message />

</flow>
```

When I run the project, sometimes it works fine and sometimes it throws the following error:

> ERROR 2015-07-17 12:37:47,620 [[rabbit_notification].amqpLocalhostConnector.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.amqp.AmqpMessageReceiver$AmqpMessageRouterWork: Impossible to route: org.mule.transport.amqp.AmqpMessage@43cac8[consumerTag=amq.ctag-jASX98hPWb7UUiIVHLOeEQ,envelope=Envelope(deliveryTag=2, redeliver=false, exchange=exchange, routingKey=file.id),body={53,53,97,57,50,49,52,98,50,50,50,57,101,56,56,51,55,101,98,54,102,100,56,53},properties=#contentHeader(content-type=null, content-encoding=UTF-8, headers={MULE_SESSION=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, MULE_ENCODING=UTF-8, MULE_ROOT_MESSAGE_ID=c628f745-2c99-11e5-b27a-e1c8fbc553ca, MULE_ENDPOINT=amqp://exchange}, delivery-mode=2, priority=0, correlation-id=null, reply-to=null, expiration=null, message-id=c628f745-2c99-11e5-b27a-e1c8fbc553ca, timestamp=Fri Jul 17 12:37:47 ART 2015, type=null, user-id=null, app-id=null, cluster-id=null)]

Does anyone knows why this could be happening?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share previous and subsequent log lines.

Comment: @VíctorRomero your comment make me realize that the error was in another component.After I retrieve a message from the queue, I hit MongoDB in order to get id-based document. This was returning NULL, so the Mule Message cannot be routed and then the previous error raised.

So, I fixed the MongoDB problem and now everything works fine. Thanks!